# Used Memory on GCP Memorystore instance despite no data in redis

Tags: redis, google-cloud-memorystore

We just created this GCP memorystore instance for redis. It shows 0.22 GB already used, however we are 100% certain that there is no data in the redis cache. We connect to the memorystore instance via a Compute Engine and run `flushall` to ensure that the cache is empty. What could possibly be the 0.22GB being used here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/memory-management-best-practices#right-size_your_cloud_memorystore_instance:%7E:text=Provision%20extra%20memory,the%20replication%20buffer.), when you are using Standard Tier on your Redis Instance, memory usage will provision an extra reserve 10% of instance capacity as a replication buffer.